# Preserve File Extension on a Controlled React Text Input

Tags: reactjs, redux, filenames

I have a simple file input in my app for storing attachments that a user uploads.

```
<input id='uploadFile' type='file' name="files" />
<label htmlFor='uploadFile' onClick={this.onFileClick}>File</label>
```

I also have a text input where they can alter the filename of the uploaded file.

```
<input id={props.id} type='text' value={props.value} onChange={(event) => props.onChangeHandler(event)} />
```

The `input` reads `props.value` from its parent, which reads the value from Redux. Everything works great. However, a user can overwrite the file extension, which leads to the file being uploaded without an extension. Yikes! My question is, how can I preserve the file extension in a controlled text input. My current thinking involves something like this:

```
// check the MIME type of the upload
let mimeType = attachmentswindow.uploadedAttachment.type;

// check the text input for presence of a "."
// if it's not there, we better add the extension!
let updatedAttachmentFilename = event.target.value.includes(".") ? 
    event.target.value :
    event.target.value + '.' + mimeType.substring(mimeType.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

// store the new file name in redux
dispatch(updateUploadedAttachmentFilename({ updatedAttachmentFilename }));
```

This sort of works, but really, I'd like to make it impossible for the user to event touch the file extension. Is there any way to do that with a controlled text input in React? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I uncovered an answer for anyone who may be curious. It's actually a pretty simple fix. Simply supply a `keydown` listener that sets the `event.target.selectionEnd` property like so:

```
onKeyDown(event) {
    event.target.selectionEnd = event.target.value.lastIndexOf(".");
}
```

A more "React" way of doing things would be to supply a `ref` to the `input` and then set the `selectionEnd` using the `ref`, but my UI structure made this a more costly and time consuming fix. Still, if anyone has any other suggestions please fire away!

Comment: Not sure if this is a possibility, but why not just show the filename (without the extension) in the input and keep the extension outside of the view. You only use it when you need to upload the file.